# How to tell if this function is not in$ L^∞ (E)$space?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I let $E＝(0,1)$ and let $f(x)＝ln(\frac{1}{x})$.
Is that $f(x)∈L^∞(E)$
I tried to use $|lnx|$ equals $|ln(\frac{1}{x})|$ and then use $|x-1|$ to shrink it, but I couldn't get the answer I was looking for and who could give me some help

Answer (score 1):

$f\notin L^∞(E)$:

Suppose $|\ln (\frac 1 x)| \leq M$ a.e. Then $|\ln (\frac 1 x)| \leq M$ on a dense set of points and, by continuity, the inequality holds for all $x \in (0,1)$. You ge  a contradiction by taking $0<x< e^{-M}$.

Comment: Could you please add some details? I don't know how to operate it specifically

Comment: Can you prove that complement of a set of measure $0$ is dense? (Use proof by contradiction). @tianhaowu

Comment: I have no idea.